# Getting MySQL Trigger Error

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, syntax-error

I've written a MySQL trigger in WordPress database & it's giving an error. My trigger code is given below :

```
CREATE 
  [DEFINER = { user | CURRENT_USER }]
  TRIGGER up_trig AFTER INSERT ON `wp_postmeta` 
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    DECLARE `pan_id` INT
    "SELECT DISTINCT (`meta_value`) INTO `pan_id`
     FROM `wp_postmeta`
     WHERE `meta_key` = 'panchayat_id' 
     AND `meta_value` = NEW.(SELECT DISTINCT meta_value 
                             FROM wp_postmeta 
                             WHERE meta_key = panchayat_id)"

    IF `pan_id` != 'NULL'  THEN
       UPDATE `wp_panchayatpost`
       SET post_count = post_count+1
       WHERE 'panchayat_id' = 'pan_id';
    END IF;
END;
```

It's giving the following error message :

> Error
>
> SQL query: Documentation
>
> CREATE [ DEFINER = {user | CURRENT_USER}]TRIGGER up_trig AFTER INSERT
>   ON `wp_postmeta` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN DECLARE `pan_id` INT "SELECT
>   DISTINCT (`meta_value`) INTO `pan_id` FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE
>   `meta_key` = 'panchayat_id' AND `meta_value` = NEW.(SELECT DISTINCT
>   meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = panchayat_id)" IF
>   `pan_id` != 'NULL' THEN UPDATE `wp_panchayatpost` SET post_count =
>   post_count +1 WHERE 'panchayat_id' = 'pan_id';

MySQL said: Documentation

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '[DEFINER = { user | CURRENT_USER }] TRIGGER up_trig
>                   AFTER INSERT ' at line 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the `[DEFINER = { user | CURRENT_USER }]`. It is required when you want to define kind of trigger owner user. Or replace it with `DEFINER=root` (or any another user name you use to connect).

Comment: Not just `[Definer ...` but the trigger body has handful of errors.

Comment: I am not compiler to point all the places. Try to run your SQL and fix errors one by one